# Is the directory /apps/ a legacy of anything?

Tags: filesystems, software-installation, fhs

Several times, I have seen in (quite) big projects, software installations made under

`/apps/`

First I thought it was a fantasy, refusing FHS normalisation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Because I have seen it in different companies on differents projects, I am begining to doubt it is a total invention of some kind.

Do you know if it is a legacy or some old practice on any system?

Where does it come from?

Comment: You are conflating the POSIX standard and the FHS.

Comment: You're right, I correct this.

Comment: That's funny, the publically available stuff I've seen like Google Chrome or VirtualBox tends to use `/opt/`.  Can you say whether any of these were public apps, or is it all private stuff there's not much point / permission for you to name?

Comment: I have never seen it. What OS? What software?